# Downloading incorrect file from google cloud storage via wget

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am able to go to the following link:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/_details/gcp-public-data-nexrad-l3-realtime/NIDS/YUX/HHC/HHC_20231120_1746;tab=live_object
```

to download a file. there are two links: the first one (public URL), when clicked, leads to an XML page. The second one (Authenticated URL) downloads the file correctly, and is only a few kB in size.

However, I want to try and use curl or wget to obtain these files in a sort of automated fashion without having to visit the webpage. One such way I have tried is:

```
wget https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcp-public-data-nexrad-l3-realtime/NIDS/YUX/HHC/HHC_20231120_1746
```

However, this seems to download a different file (a few hundred kB in size) that is not the proper file requested (i.e., the file is 'corrupt' compared to the file that I get when I click on the authenticated URL to download the file). What might the issue be here?

Comment: Google uses authorization via headers and cookies which are encrypted and are generated during the browser session with Google. You must use supported methods (public, OAuth, Signed URLs) to access Cloud Storage.

Comment: Did you check the content type of the file?